# Hide notes from audience using DS PDF Viewer

Tags: pdf, presentations

I am doing a presentation using the DS PDF Viewer. I typed the presentation in LaTeX using beamer as the document class. I have all the notes on the right hand side, but when I open it with the DS PDF viewer, the audience see my notes as well. How do I hide the note side from the audience, leaving only the main presentation side for them to see? Please help...My presentation starts in a few hours. Thank you.

Comment: What is DS PDF Viewer exactly? Is it the viewer described on https://dspdfviewer.danny-edel.de/? If yes, then according to that page you may be able to press `F12` or `S` on the keyboard to swap screens.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen it...but that still displays the notes to the audience...Once again, thanks

Comment: Another issue may be that your projector is set to 'clone mode', i.e., display the same as your presenter laptop/pc. For the notes to be shown just to you you need to set the projector to 'extended mode' or something similar. You can change the settings in your operating system config tools, search for 'monitor', 'screen', 'display' or something similar in the configuration menus (the exact name and place where to find it is different for each operating system of course).

Comment: You're right...and I thank you for everything...Can you write that as an answer, so I can accept, please? It has resolved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Dual-Screen PDF Viewer it is necessary to set the projector to "extended mode", i.e., display a second, different desktop on the second screen. If you see the same output on both screens then the projector is set to "clone mode" or "mirror mode" where the second screen just shows a copy of the first screen.

The procedure to change the projector settings is different for each operating system (or different desktop environments for the same operating system).

- Windows 10: press Windows logo key + <kbd>P</kbd>. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-multiple-monitors-in-windows-10-329c6962-5a4d-b481-7baa-bec9671f728a
- MacOS: Apple menu, System Preferences, click Displays, then click Arrangement. See https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl7c7ebe08/mac.
- Ubuntu (Gnome): Open Activities (for example using the Windows key), type Displays. See https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html.

See also https://github.com/dannyedel/dspdfviewer/issues/193 for a related Github issue for DS PDF Viewer with a terminal-orented solution.